# Is it possible to use AVFoundation to take a picture using PCL project

Tags: ios, xamarin, avfoundation, cross-platform

I'm fairly new to Xamarin, and I was handed a PCL project and asked to add the option to take a picture "within" the application (not by simply calling the camera app). For iOS, it seems the only way to do this is using the AVFoundation library. However, when I went to look into the issue, it seems that they're relying on using UIKit and UIView controls to accomplish their tasks. Is there anyway I can implement this into my PCL project? Maybe by using a DependencyService? I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Where is AVFoundation dependent on UIKit controls? Most apps also need camera preview which requires a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer which inherits from CALayer which is in the core animation framework.

Comment: right, but from what I'm seeing here (and I'm no expert whatsoever), it's needing a UIView to set the frame for it.
videoPreviewLayer = new AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer (captureSession) {
    Frame = this.View.Frame
   };

Comment: At some point you are going to have to display the preview so you will need a UIView. But you shouldn't need to supply the UIView to the PCL. Can you post this code plus some of it's surrounding code into your question.

Comment: That code is just from a sample project I downloaded which uses a storyboard file which I won't have access to since I'm using xaml files to display my pages. Is there another way to display UIViews to the screen then?

Comment: The preview layer will eventually need to interact with a UIView if it is to be displayed, but it shouldn’t need to inside your PCL

Comment: Did you try the PCL friendly plugin [CrossMedia](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin)?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by using a CustomPageRenderer in the iOS portion of the app. I borrowed a lot of code from [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/ContentPage).